# Kivy drawn items 'disappearing' (or possible render order problem)

Tags: python, kivy

(this is a repost from https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/kivy-users/0B5GYWkTIwE/-OQYp_ykCQAJ)

Very occasionally our kivy-based UI glitches in a very odd way: the system remains responsive and the displays of buttons and text work but it seems that all "drawn" items disappear, i.e. items from kivy.graphics.

Here is the main control screen in it's proper state:
[image: Correct operation]

and when it goes wrong it changes to:

[image: Broken render]

All the items rendered with the kivy.graphics objects have gone!

This is using 1.9.1-1build3 (in Ubuntu) and 1.9.1-dev (from kivypie on an RPi)

Does anyone have a clue as to what might be causing this or how to track it down? It seems to happen on touch events, but it is so rare it's been impossible so far to find any commonality and there is no error report output to stdout/stderr or the .kivy/log/

Here's a section of code showing how elements are being drawn:

```
class LineWidget(GUIWidget):
    """A line widget. A simple sequence of points"""
    def __init__(self, points, width, **kwargs):
        GUIWidget.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.points = points
        with self.canvas:
            self.line_color = theme.system.line.Color()
            self.line = Line(width=width)
        self.bind(size=self.update_rect, pos=self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, instance, value):
        """Update the point positions."""
        self.pos = instance.pos
        if self.points:
            self.line.points = self.get_points(self.points)

    def set_color(self, color):
        """Change the color"""
        self.line_color.rgb = color
```

and the blue/grey background is rendered:

```
with self.canvas.before:
    if background_color is None:
        background_color = theme.primary.black
    self._background_color = Color(*background_color)
    self._background_rectangle = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
```

- In my post to the kivy group, it has been suggested that maybe some race condition has happened resulting in the native kivy objects being rendered on top of mine and to try using canvas.after, but unless I can find a way to provoke the problem I'll never know if this has worked.
- Is it possible that the render order (Z-index) has changed?
- Is it possible there is some race condition?
- The problem happens so rarely it has been impossible so far to
  provoke the problem (100s of random clicks on widgets is the only
  way) - is there some programmatic method to try and force the issue?
- what debug could I put in to try and find out what might be
  happening?

Thanks,

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you find any workaround for this issue?

Comment: No, was never resolved